# Docker non-root access: Error loading config file:stat /home/wu/.docker/config.json

Tags: docker

I finished the docker installation with non-root access, namely

```
1.define a docker user group
2.add my current user to the docker group
```

pass the test

```
docker run --rm hello-world
```

but when I start to provision my docker containers, somewhere in the procedure I got the error:

```
Error loading config file:stat /home/user/.docker/config.json:Permission Denied
```

seems to be docker is trying to access some resources but got denied

What is happening here? How could I fix this ?

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got the same error after upgrate from 1.4 to latest.
Fix: manually create .docker/config.json ( put empty json object there {} ) and set ownership like this :

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser docker /home/myuser/.docker/config.json
```

Answer (score 22):

It may be that the .docker folder and the .docker/json.config file is not owned by the current user.

Try this:

```
sudo chown $USER:docker ~/.docker
sudo chown $USER:docker ~/.docker/config.json
sudo chmod g+rw ~/.docker/config.json
```

Comment: This is the actual answer, I can now run docker without using sudo

Answer (score 1):

Simply grant your current user to access the /.docker folder and your warning will get vanished in thin air.
Run this on your terminal:

```
sudo chown $USER:docker ~/.docker
```